# Size of json to upload (import) on Firebase database

Tags: firebase, firebase-realtime-database, firebase-console

I can upload, e.g. json file in 10kb to Firebase database.
But when I want to upload more, e.g. json file in 30kb or 70kb it shows an error `"There was a problem contacting the server. Try uploading your file again"`:

[image]

Comment: Are you sure the JSON is correct?

Comment: I've uploaded JSON that was way larger than that: 10MB+.

Comment: @AndréKool it would say if it had a mistake. I tried to make a mistake in json file on purpose and then uploaded it to database, and then it says `"Invalid JSON file"`. So yeah, I'm sure that my JSON is correct

Comment: @cartant are you also using a free account?

Comment: Same problem here - @user25 I am using a free account

Comment: Yes, I've uploaded at least 10MB to a free account on numerous occasions. It could just be that something weird is happening at the moment. Or, are you sure the larger file doesn't have significantly different content? Like arrays or something?

Comment: https://status.firebase.google.com/ - looks like the console is having a service disruption atm. - Which makes sense, bc the DB is still saving / retrieving - i just cant perform admin actions via the console @user25

Comment: @cartant there is nothing special in my json file, no arrays, every child has the same structure and they contains only text (String type)

Comment: @BrandtSolovij latest was `Incident began at 2016-08-21 00:21 and ended at 2016-08-21 00:25 (all times are US/Pacific).` but today is 22

Comment: @user25 - not the Realtime DB - the `CONSOLE`  - the console performs the update actions via the firebase admin webpage. the `Console` is actively experiencing a disruption this morning

Comment: @BrandtSolovij oh, my fault)

Comment: Since this is a server side issue with firebase console i'm going to vote to close this question as off-topic

Comment: @AndréKool is it so important to you?)

Comment: @AndréKool is right this is technically offtopic to stackoverflow. Perhaps rather than close it should be moved to `SuperUser` forum ? That forum deals more with software use like this imho @user25

Comment: I just uploaded a 36K JSON file without problems. If you are still having problems, you might want to try a different browser. If that doesn't help, see if you can upload the JSON through the API. A simple `ref.set(json)` may work or show more clearly what's going wrong.

Comment: @FrankvanPuffelen I was trying at work using Firefox. Now at home I'm trying again using Chrome, but still the same error. I'm trying upload 82kb json file. `ref.set(json)`, thanks, I'll try

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Please first refer to the status dashboard:

https://status.firebase.google.com/

At time of question - the console was experiencing a service disruption - which is why you can read / write to the DB via your application but can not perform admin tasks via the console.

Note the location is substantially above the RTDB

[image]